# How to apply customized sort with jquery i.e. from an array

Tags: jquery, html

I have requirement like display Div as columns when mobile mode is on. Let me explain my requirement. let say i have 3 rows 4 div each as below

Div1 Div2 Div3 Div4
Div5 Div6 Div7 Div8
Div9 Div10 Div11 Div12

When mobile mode is on above Div will be display as below with single row, as code is in responsive mode

Div1
Div2
Div3
Div4
Div5
Div6
Div7
Div8
.
.
.
Div12

But i need to display as columns when in desktop mode i.e. I need to sort with jquery such that Divs should display like

Div1
Div5

### Div9

Div2
Div6

### Div10

Div3
Div7

### Div11

Div4
Div8
Div12

Could some one please help me to achieve above sort with jquery?

Answer (score 0):

This would be easier achieved via media queries, I suggest you take a look:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

I'd also suggest taking a look at Bootstrap (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/) as it provided an easy way to accomplish what you're looking for with minimal effort in terms of CSS.

**Example:**

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div name="div1" class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
      your content
    </div>
    
    <div name="div2" class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
      your content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This example code will use Bootstraps grid system (12 columns from left to right) and divide the space between divs based on what you specify. In this case, when the screen is a width of 576px, the divs will be on top of each other, and if the screen is a width of 992px or more, they will sit next to each other.

My explanation may be a bit lacking, but I definitely recommend having a read over the documentation.